# Unrecognized union type argument

Tags: types, f#

I have the following union and helper functions in F#:

```
type ParsedItem =
    | Digit of char
    | Operator of char
    | Alpha of char
    | NotParsed of char

let private digits = ['0'..'9']@['.']
let private opers = ['!';'%';'^';'*';'(';')';'+';'=';'<';'>']
let private alphas =['A'..'Z']@['a'..'z']

let (|IsDigitChar|_|) ch =
    match List.exists(fun a->a=ch) digits with
    | true -> Some IsDigitChar
    | _ -> None

let (|IsOperChar|_|) ch =
    match List.exists(fun a->a=ch) opers with
    | true -> Some IsOperChar
    | _ -> None

let (|IsAlphaChar|_|) ch =
    match List.exists(fun a->a=ch) alphas with
    | true -> Some IsAlphaChar
    | _ -> None

let parseChar ch =
    match ch with
    | IsDigitChar -> Digit(ch)
    | IsOperChar -> Operator(ch)
    | IsAlphaChar -> Alpha(ch)
    | _ -> NotParsed(ch)
```

But the type "Digit" is not recognized in the following function:

```
let coalesceDigits (dgts: Digit list) =  
    [|for Digit d in dgts -> d|] |> string
```

As the compiler gives the following warning on the `(dgts: Digit list)` argument:
`The type 'Digit' is not defined'`

However, it also gives the following warning for the `Digit d` in the function body `[|for Digit d in ...` : `Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. For example, the value 'Alpha (_)' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s).` So it recognizes it as a `ParsedItem` in the body, but not in the declaration?

How do I get the compiler to recognize that `Digit` is indeed a type without having to declare it outside of `ParsedItem`, or must I declare`Digit` and the others as their own type and then add them to `ParsedItem` as follows?

```
type Digit = Digit of char
[...]
type ParsedItem =
    | Digit of Digit
    | Operator of Operator
    | ... (etc)
```

Answer (score 4):

`Digit` is not a type.

`ParsedItem` is a type, but `Digit` is not, and neither are `Operator`, `Alpha`, and `NotParsed`.

Using that syntax, you have defined a type `ParsedItem`, whose values can come in four flavors - `Digit`, `Operator`, `Alpha`, or `NotParsed`.

You can create new values of type `ParsedItem` by specifying which flavor you'd like to create and any parameters that flavor requires (in your case all flavors have one `char` parameter), like this:

```
let item1 = Digit 'a'
let item2 = Operator 'b'
// and so on
```

In this example both `item1` and `item2` are values of type `ParsedItem`. They are *not* values of different types.

If you have a value of type `ParsedItem`, you can find out what flavor it is by pattern matching:

```
let whatIsIt item =
    match item with
    | Digit c -> "It's a digit!"
    | Operand c -> "It's an operand!"
    | Alpha c -> "It's an alpha!"
    | NotParsed c -> "Not parsed :-/"

printfn "%s" (whatIsIt item1) // prints "It's a digit!"
printfn "%s" (whatIsIt item2) // prints "It's an operator!"
```

If you miss a flavor when writing a pattern match, the compiler will catch you:

```
let whatIsIt item =
    match item with
    | Digit c -> "It's a digit!"
    // Warning: incomplete pattern match
```

With this warning the compiler is telling you: "I see you have defined what to do if `item` happens to be `Digit`, but what am I supposed to do with the other three flavors?"

This is what happens in your code, too: you pattern match on `Digit d`, but you don't specific what to do for the other flavors.

---

Now, I don't know what you're trying to achieve here, and your code is kind of nonsensical (for the reasons described above), so the best I can do is explain what you misunderstand about the language syntax. If you elaborate on your actual goal, I may be able to suggest a correct way of encoding it.

Comment: I have clarified but it looks like I'm going to have to make `Digit` its own type according to what both you and @Nhgia Bui answered

Answer (score 3):

`Digit` is not a type, it is a tag/case of the type `ParsedItem`

Thus, you need to explicitly create a type `Digit`, and use it in the tag `Digit` of `ParsedItem`. Compiler knows how to distinguish this so the same name `Digit` is not a problem.

```
type Digit = DigitValue of char
type ParsedItem =
    | Digit of Digit ...
let coalesceDigits (dgts: Digit list) =  
    [|for (DigitValue d) in dgts -> d|] |> string
```

Comment: So I have to declare `Digit` outside as its own type no matter what, is what I'm getting from both you and Fyodor's answer?

Comment: It depends on what you want to pass to the coalesceDigits function. If it must be a Digit list, then you can do as I described. If it must be a ParsedItem list, then inside the function you have to filter first to get the list of digits only.

Comment: Also, don’t hestitate to creat many types in F#. Types are our friends, not an annoyance. I recommend this series about Designing the domain with F# types https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/ddd/